# how to state boost_serialization_split_member for non-intrusive function definitions

Tags: serialization, boost

in the tutorial it is explained how to split load and save functions, but the boost_serialization_split_member() declaration was inside the class.

**How do you declare a class being split to two functions externally?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section of the docs labeled, "[Splitting serialize into save/load](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splitting)" explains how to do this. Basically, you have two template functions, `save` and `load`, for the type in question, defined in the `boost::serialization` namespace. Then you use the `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_FREE` macro.